# Adding pagination when displaying a custom category

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add pagination for custom entries created through the CPT UI.

```
        <?php $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1; ?>
        <?php
          $query = new WP_Query( array(
              'post_type' => array( 'feedbacks' ),
              'posts_per_page'   => 1,
              'paged'          => $paged,
          ));
        ?>
        <?php if ($query->have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();?>
          //post
        <?php endwhile;?>
        <?php endif; ?>

      </div>
      <?php

        $big = 999999999;

          echo paginate_links( array(
          'base'    => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
          'format'  => '?paged=%#%',
          'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
          'total'   => $query ->max_num_pages
        ));
       ?>
```

Pagination appears. But when you go to the second page gives 404.

We partially managed to solve the problem by adding the is archive attribute for the custom post type and changing the type of permalinks to default ones. In this case, everything works, but you need links with the page name

Comment: Try this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/176723/creating-a-simple-pagination-for-custom-post-type-templates

Comment: Enable query variable in ceated custom post type function